# rets-python with flask cannot return as json

Tags: python, json, flask, rets

I am doing a project which has to do with `rets`, somehow my collaborator has problem using `rets-client` for `js` during installation.
Anyways, so I decided to find `python` instead which I found `rets-python` from https://github.com/opendoor-labs/rets

I am able to get data returned from `rets`, somehow I wanted to make an `api` so I installed `flask` (new with flask)

However I tried to return the data into `JSON` I just kept on getting errors

I this is my code

```
import json

from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def mls():
    from rets.client import RetsClient

    client = RetsClient(
        login_url='xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        username='xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        password='xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        # Ensure that you are using the right auth_type for this particular MLS
        # auth_type='basic',
        # Alternatively authenticate using user agent password
        user_agent='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        user_agent_password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )

    resource = client.get_resource('Property')
    print(resource)

    resource.key_field

    print(resource.key_field)

    resource_class = resource.get_class('RD_1')
    print(resource_class)

    search_result = resource_class.search(query='(L_Status=1_0)', limit=2)
```

I will write my returns here as I have tried few different returns

```
    # return jsonify(results=search_result.data)
    # TypeError: <Record: Property:RD_1:259957852> is not JSON serializable

    return Response(json.dumps(search_result.data), mimetype='application/json')
    # TypeError: <Record: Property:RD_1:259957852> is not JSON serializable

    return json.dumps(search_result.data)
    # TypeError: <Record: Property:RD_1:259957852> is not JSON serializable
```

I event tried making the results into dict such as `dict(search_result.data)` which gives me errors like `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`

if I try to get the `print(type(search_result.data[0].data))` this is the return `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>`  I tried to `jsonify`, `json.dump` and also with `Response` with just this one record with or without `dict()` I get this error `TypeError: Decimal('1152') is not JSON serializable`

also `print(type(search_result.data))` gives `tuple`

Anyone able to give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance for any help and advises.

Comment: What is `search_result.data`?

Comment: @geckos gives data in `tuple`